# GET flash memory type: SLC or MLC

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Just for my knowledge, I would like to know whether the type of flash memory used in my pendrive is SLC or MLC. Is there a way to find it out? I googled but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the pendrives are using NAND MLC. SLC pendrives are rare and usually more expensive. Some examples:

- [Zalman U3M16 16GB SLC Flash Drive](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/4839/zalman_u3m16_16gb_slc_flash_drive_review/index.html)
- [Mach Xtreme MX-ES Ultra SLC USB 3.0 Flash Drive](http://www.thessdreview.com/featured/mach-xtreme-mx-es-ultra-slc-usb-3-0-flash-drive-review-64gb/)
- [Lexar JumpDrive Triton 32GB USB 3.0 Flash Drive](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/5209/lexar-jumpdrive-triton-32gb-usb-3-0-flash-drive-review/index.html)
- [IronKey S200 1GB USB flash drive](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/ironkey/s200/326148/)

I am sure with a little googling you will find more. Interestingly most of the Workspace pendrives, which should be endurable, use MLC, so I guess that is sufficient as well, and we don't really need SLC.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was given by Mechanical Snail(check the comments above) on Stack Exchange. The answer's brief and simple, every Flash device uses a MLC because it is cheap and has a higher density. Giving SLC to the customer would make the pendrive costly as cost per gigabyte for SLC is more than MLC. For uses like these MLC is always preferred over SLC.